# scala collections to string

Tags: scala, scala-collections

All, I am new to scala and I had a question
I need to convert list of case class to string similar to this

```
unit1 res_1
unit1 res_2
unit1 res_3

case class Items(unitId: String, residents: List[String])
```

I am trying something like this

```
val l : List[Items]

val mappingList = l.map(item => {
  item.residents.map(r => item.unitId + ' ' + r )
}).flatten

mappingList.mkString('\n')
```

Can anyone suggest better way?

Thanks
Swetha

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. You can simplify by collapsing `map` followed by `flatten` into `flatMap`:

```
case class Items(unitId: String, residents: List[String])

def itemsToString(l: List[Items]): String =
  l.flatMap { item =>
    item.residents.map(r => item.unitId + ' ' + r)
  } .mkString("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

This sort of problem is often more clear using a for comprehension:

```scala
val mappingList = for {
  item <- l
  resident <- item.residents
} yield item.unitId + ' ' + resident

mappingList mkString "\n"
```